# CoreLocation singleton delegate methods used by multiple views

Tags: objective-c, ios, singleton, notifications, core-location

I've implemented a singleton CoreLocation class (courtesy of this link:  http://jinru.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/singletons-in-objective-c-an-example-of-cllocationmanager/)

However, I need two different ViewControllers to access the delegate method "newLocation".  One viewController manages identification of locations.  Another manages a mapView.

Ideally, I want both viewControllers to be delegates of my singleton - so they can both handle the "newLocation" method. But is this advisable (and if so, how would I do it)?

Or should I be using notifications to achieve this?  With the singleton posting a notification, and the ViewControllers listening to them?

Any advice, much appreciated.

dunc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with posting notifications with `NSNotificationCenter`.